# Connect to hidden WiFi using netsh commands

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, wifi, netsh

I would like to know if it is possible to connect to a hidden WiFi network knowing the SSDI name and password.
I did try to do this by myself but without any luck.

For some tests, I made hidden WiFi with the SSID name Galaxy and a password.

Firstly tried to add a profile by making a .xml file with the specified parameters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>GalaxyNet</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>Galaxy</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <autoSwitch>true</autoSwitch>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>       
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>**** password ****</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

After that added the profile from .xml file using netsh commands.

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="c:\NET.xml"
```

Got a message:

```
Profile GalaxyNet is added on interface Wi-Fi.
```

After everything went ok with the previous steps I tried to connect to that profile but with no luck.

```
netsh wlan connect name="GalaxyNet" interface="wi-fi"
The network specified by profile "GalaxyNet" is not available to connect.
```

Also tried:

```
netsh wlan connect ssid="Galaxy" name="GalaxyNet" interface="wi-fi"
The network specified by profile "GalaxyNet" is not available to connect.
```

Is it even possible to somehow match the netsh hidden network to a profile if it wasn't "assigned" with a GUI interface?

Or does anyone know another way to connect to a hidden WiFi by any script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile configuration setting you're missing is `nonBroadcast` - it controls whether the profile is allowed to connect to visibly broadcasting SSIDs only, or attempt to connect to hidden networks.

You can set it for an existing profile with `netsh wlan set profileparameter`:

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter name=GalaxyNet nonBroadcast=yes
```

Or include it in your XML file under `/WLANProfile/SSIDConfig` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>GalaxyNet</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>Galaxy</name>
        </SSID>
        <nonBroadcast>true</nonBroadcast>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <!-- rest of xml goes here as before -->
</WLANProfile>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a really great and fast tip for me.